Pattern matching with predicates support
TL;DR
https://godbolt.org/z/TMfb8z99h
static std::string match(const std::variant<int, double, std::string, std::vector<int>> &v) {
    return
      v >>= m
      // matches `int`
      | [](int i) { return std::to_string(i); }
      // matches `std::string`
      | [](const std::string &s) { return s; }
      // only matches `double`, since `int` has been matched above
      | m_if<std::is_fundamental>([](double d) { return std::to_string(d); })
      // matches `std::vector<int, Allocator>`, can also be 
      // m_is<std::vector, int, traits::_ph>
      | m_is<std::vector, int>([](const auto& v) {
            int sum = 0; 
            for (int i: v) sum += i; 
            return std::to_string(sum); });
}

int main() {
    std::cout 
      << match("oceanic")
      << '\n' << match(815) 
      << '\n' << match(23.42)
      << '\n' << match(std::vector{4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42});

In detail
I wanted a nice and neat interface for pattern matching an std::variant-like structure that can be used (initially) as part of my library's API utilities.

Why not just std::visit?
It's invocation in itself is overly verbose.
Why not just use a set of if constexpr in the labmda-visitor?
It works only starting from C++17, whilst I am aiming for a public API usable as early as at least C++11 (if possible).
... And it also adds to boilerplate (need to write using T = std::decay_t<decltype(v)>; every time) and if constexpr itself is rather long.
Why not just go with overloaded{...} lambda set?
The main reason you can guess from the example usage I have provided above: using template predicates is not possible. Matching templates "ignoring" allocators also requires some additional work (before C++20, where template lambdas become available).
... And it is impossible to use with callable types declared as final. Not a deal breaker though.

Interface and design decisions
For the simplest implementation possible I decided to construct the matching object in-place and invoke it in a single expression.

For matching: m, global inline constant used for overloading.
For general predicates: m_if<predicate_template, templ_args...>. For example: m_if<is_fundamental> or m_if<is_same, int>.
For direct type and template matching: m_is.
For example:

m_is<int> matches int,
m_is<std::basic_string> matches all the specializations
m_is<std::vector, int> matches all the specializatioins of std::vector<int, AllocatorT>
m_is<std::array, int> matches all the std::array<int, N>. Possible, because function templates support overloads, unlike class templates.
[](const std::string&) {} matches fully specialized std::string. Only non-template lambdas and callable types with a single operator() overload are acceptable, because the argument is used for m_is<Arg>.


For collecting matches: operator|, I believe that no explanation is needed.
For invocation: operator>>= and operator<<= just because of the precedence. And operator(), it is less confusing for functional folks, but invocation is not that clean.
constexpr invocation should be possible.

Can it blow up in your face?
All the types must be matched, otherwise a compile-time error. For example, if I uncomment m_if<std::is_fundamental> case, I get:

Clang: the very first line allows to understand which type (double) was not handled

<source>:123:20: error: static assertion failed due to requirement '(double *)nullptr , false': unmatched Type
  123 |     static_assert(((T*)nullptr, Matched), "unmatched Type");


GCC: ugly as always, but T = double can be seen from the first line

<source>: In instantiation of 'constexpr std::size_t traits::{anonymous}::_find_match(std::bool_constant<Matched>) [with T = double; long unsigned int I = 2; bool Matched = false; std::size_t = long unsigned int; std::bool_constant<Matched> = std::bool_constant<false>]':
<source>:132:45:   required from 'constexpr std::size_t traits::{anonymous}::_find_match(std::false_type) [with T = double; long unsigned int I = 0; Match = _match<traits::_bind<traits::is_same_type, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::pred, match(const std::variant<int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >&)::<lambda(const std::string&)> >; Matches = {_match<traits::_bind<traits::is_template_bind<std::vector, int>::pred>::pred, match(const std::variant<int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >&)::<lambda(const auto:30&)> >}; std::size_t = long unsigned int; std::false_type = std::false_type]'
  132 |     return _find_match<T, I + 1, Matches...>(Match::template value<T>);
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Redundant matches are not supported at this point
Limitations
It is practically impossible to compare 2 templates of different signatures, so the cases like m_is<std::array> are ad hoc'ed.
Implementation

#include <variant>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

namespace traits {

template <typename T, typename = decltype(&T::operator())>
struct callable_arg;

template <typename T, typename Arg, typename Ret>
struct callable_arg<T, Ret(T::*)(Arg)> {
    using type = Arg;
};

template <typename T, typename Arg, typename Ret>
struct callable_arg<T, Ret(T::*)(Arg) const> {
    using type = Arg;
};

template <typename T>
using callable_arg_t = typename callable_arg<T>::type;

template <template <typename, typename...> class Pred, typename ... Args>
struct _bind {
    template <typename T>
    using pred = Pred<T, Args...>;
};

/// placeholder to ignore types
struct _ph {};

template <typename L, typename R>
struct is_same : std::is_same<L, R> {};

template <typename L>
struct is_same<L, _ph> : std::true_type {};

template <typename R>
struct is_same<_ph, R> : std::true_type {};

template <typename ... List>
struct list_t;

template <typename, typename ...>
struct _is_subset_of;

template <typename ... Of>
struct _is_subset_of<list_t<>, Of...> : std::true_type {};

// gcc will not compile without it
template <>
struct _is_subset_of<list_t<>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename ... T>
struct _is_subset_of<list_t<T...>> : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, typename ... Ts, typename Of, typename ... Ofs>
struct _is_subset_of<list_t<T, Ts...>, Of, Ofs...> : 
    std::conditional<is_same<T, Of>::value, 
        _is_subset_of<list_t<Ts...>, Ofs...>, 
        std::false_type>::type {};

template <typename ... T>
struct list_t {
    template <typename ... Of>
    struct is_subset_of : _is_subset_of<list_t<T...>, Of...> {};
};

// example/check
static_assert(list_t<>::is_subset_of<>::value == std::true_type::value);
static_assert(list_t<>::is_subset_of<int>::value == std::true_type::value);
static_assert(list_t<int>::is_subset_of<int>::value == std::true_type::value);
static_assert(list_t<int>::is_subset_of<int, double>::value == std::true_type::value);
static_assert(list_t<>::is_subset_of<int, double>::value == std::true_type::value);
static_assert(list_t<int>::is_subset_of<>::value != std::true_type::value);
static_assert(list_t<_ph>::is_subset_of<int, double>::value == std::true_type::value);

template <typename Arg, typename T>
struct is_same_type : is_same<std::remove_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<Arg>>, T> {};

template <typename, template <typename...> class, typename ...>
struct is_template : std::false_type {};

template <template <typename...> class Templ, typename ... Args, typename ... SpecArgs>
struct is_template<Templ<Args...>, Templ, SpecArgs...> 
    : list_t<SpecArgs...>::template is_subset_of<Args...> {};

template <template <typename, typename...> class Templ, typename ... SpecArgs>
struct is_template_bind {
    template <typename T>
    using pred = is_template<T, Templ, SpecArgs...>;
};

template <typename T, template <typename> class...>
struct foldl;

template <typename T, template <typename> class Pred>
struct foldl<T, Pred> {
    using type = typename Pred<T>::type;
};

template <typename T, template <typename> class Left,
    template <typename> class ... Right>
struct foldl<T, Left, Right...> : foldl<typename Left<T>::type, Right...> {};

template <typename T, template <typename> class ... List>
using foldl_t = typename foldl<T, List...>::type;

// example/check
static_assert(
    std::is_same_v<
        int,
        foldl_t<int const&, 
            std::remove_reference,
            std::remove_const
            >>);

namespace {
template <typename T, std::size_t I, bool Matched>
constexpr static std::size_t _find_match(std::bool_constant<Matched>) noexcept {
    static_assert(((T*)nullptr, Matched), "unmatched Type");
    return I;
}

template <typename T, std::size_t I, typename ...>
constexpr static std::size_t _find_match(std::true_type) noexcept { return I; }

template <typename T, std::size_t I, typename Match, typename ... Matches>
constexpr static std::size_t _find_match(std::false_type) noexcept {
    return _find_match<T, I + 1, Matches...>(Match::template value<T>);
}

template <typename T, typename Match, typename ... Matches>
constexpr static std::size_t find_match() noexcept {
    return _find_match<T, 0, Matches...>(Match::template value<T>);
}
} // namespace
} // namespace traits

template <template <typename> class Pred, typename Callable>
struct _match {
    template <typename T>
    constexpr static auto value = std::bool_constant<Pred<T>{}>();

    Callable _callable;
};

template <template <typename, typename...> class Pred, typename ... Args, typename Callable>
constexpr auto m_if(Callable c) noexcept
-> _match<traits::_bind<Pred, Args...>::template pred, Callable> {
    return {c};
}

template <typename T, typename Callable>
constexpr auto m_is(Callable c) noexcept {
    return m_if<traits::is_same_type, T>(c);
}

template <template <typename, typename...> class Templ, typename ... SpecArgs, 
    typename Callable>
constexpr auto m_is(Callable c) {
    return m_if<traits::is_template_bind<Templ, SpecArgs...>::template pred>(c);
}

template <typename ... Matches>
struct _m {
    std::tuple<Matches...> _matches;

    template <template <typename...> class Variant, typename ... T>
    constexpr decltype(auto) operator()(const Variant<T...> &var) { return _visit(var); }

    template <template <typename...> class Variant, typename ... T>
    constexpr decltype(auto) operator()(Variant<T...> &var) { return _visit(var); }

    template <template <typename...> class Variant, typename ... T>
    constexpr decltype(auto) operator()(Variant<T...> &&var) { return _visit(std::move(var)); }

private:
    template <typename Variant>
    constexpr decltype(auto) _visit(Variant &&var) {
        // todo: remove dependency on `std::visit`
        return std::visit(
            [&](auto && v) -> decltype(auto) {
                return std::get<
                    traits::find_match<std::decay_t<decltype(v)>, Matches...>()
                >(_matches)._callable(std::forward<decltype(v)>(v));
            }, std::forward<Variant>(var));
    }
};

template <typename ... Matches, template <typename> class Pred, typename Callable>
constexpr auto operator|(_m<Matches...> lhs, _match<Pred, Callable> rhs) noexcept 
    -> _m<Matches..., _match<Pred, Callable>> {
        return {std::tuple_cat(lhs._matches, std::make_tuple(rhs))};
}

template <typename ... Matches, typename Callable, 
    typename = std::void_t<decltype(&Callable::operator())>>
constexpr auto operator|(_m<Matches...> ms, Callable non_template_c) noexcept {
    return ms | 
        m_is<traits::foldl_t<traits::callable_arg_t<Callable>,
            std::remove_reference, 
            std::remove_const>>(non_template_c);
}

template <typename ... Matches, typename Variant>
constexpr decltype(auto) operator<<=(_m<Matches...> m, Variant &&var) {
    return m(std::forward<Variant>(var));
}

template <typename ... Matches, typename Variant>
constexpr decltype(auto) operator>>=(Variant &&var, _m<Matches...> m) {
    return m(std::forward<Variant>(var));
}

const inline _m<> m{};

Examples:
auto dummy() {
    constexpr auto _1 = 
    m
    | [](int i){ return i; }
    | [](double i){ return int(i); }
    <<= std::variant<int, double>{815};
    static_assert(815 == _1);

    constexpr auto _2 = 
    std::variant<int, double>{108.0} 
    >>= m
    | [](int i){ return i; }
    | [](double i){ return int(i); };
    static_assert(108 == _2);

    return _1;
}

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

static std::string match(const std::variant<int, double, std::string, std::vector<int>> &v) {
    return
      v >>= m
      // matches `int`
      | [](int i) { return std::to_string(i); }
      // matches `std::string`
      | [](const std::string &s) { return s; }
      // only matches `double`, since `int` has been matched above
      | m_if<std::is_fundamental>([](double d) { return std::to_string(d); })
      // matches `std::vector<int, Allocator>`, can also be 
      // m_is<std::vector, int, traits::_ph>
      | m_is<std::vector, int>([](const auto& v) {
            int sum = 0; 
            for (int i: v) sum += i; 
            return std::to_string(sum); });
}

int main() {
    std::cout 
      << match("oceanic")
      << '\n' << match(815) 
      << '\n' << match(23.42)
      << '\n' << match(std::vector{4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42});
}
```


std::variant only exists since C++17, but you want to support pattern matching on a std::variant in C++11?

@indi I said std::variant-like, that is https://github.com/mpark/variant for example

Okay, but there’s still a bunch of C++17 stuff in there. Like std::bool_constant. Given that more than 70-odd% of C++ developers are already using C++17 or better, maybe sticking with C++11 isn’t really worth it.

@indi as I've also mentioned, it is (initially) part of my library's utility, which is targeted to older versions of Linux, where it is rather hard to get C++17. And I believe that most of the stuff in the code can be adapted to C++11. But I put interface and usability over the implementation (which could be adjusted), so I expect either a better/simpler alternative given the requirements, or an assessment of the proposed solution.

I don’t think what you are attempting is even possible before C++17. That is because the protocols for sum types simply… don’t exist… before C++17. You have already noticed this in your code: you’re using the C++17 protocol (std::visit) because… you must… there is no other option. You could, theoretically, invent your own protocol… but now you need to get every other sum type—including std::visit—to recognize it. To put it bluntly… not gonna happen; nobody is going to put effort into X protocol when std protocol exists. So, again… maybe sticking with C++11 isn’t worth it.

@indi I'm using std::visit here just for godbolt.mpark::visit works just fine otherwise

I’m sure mpark::visit works just fine… but std::visit will not (obviously), nor will anything else that uses the standard visiting protocol (which is std::visit, std::holds_alternative, etc.), and that is the problem; this will literally only work for your one bespoke type. Which is fine if that’s what you want, but if you want to support actual std::visit-like types—aka the standard visiting protocol—you need C++17 or later.

@indi I wrote a comment in response to Sliepen's answer. I have removed the invocation of std::visit and now pattern_t is just a callable that can be used both in std::visit like any other lambda. I removed dependencies on C++17 features here https://godbolt.org/z/6n6bYneYx However, auto in forward declarations and decltype(auto) are C++14. With them the actual interface can be seen right in the beginning of the header

@indi also, I think you are missing the point of the question. std::visit in it's default form is very verbose and ugly. I am not the first (nor the last) person who wants pattern-matching out of the box. If there's an interface that allows to match types, there would be no need to use std::visit or std::holds_alternative. match(v) | a | b c; looks way cleaner than std::visit(overloaded{a, b, c}, v);

Improve the API
When I read v >>= m, I see that v was the function parameter, but what is m? This is a very bad name for a global variable of something with a very specific function. I also don't see why you want to use the >>= operator here; it looks like a shift-assignment, which it definitely is not. I suggest changing the syntax so you'd write something like:
return pattern_matcher(v)
       | [](int i){ return std::to_string(i); }
       | …;

By using operator| you also had to introduce other types in the global namespace, such as m_if and m_is. Consider instead creating member functions of the matcher object, so you'd write something like this:
return pattern_matcher(v)
       .match([](int i){ … })
       .match([](const std::string& s){ … })
       .match_if<std::is_fundamental>([](double d){ … })
       .match_type<std::vector, int>([](const auto& v) {…});

Another option would be to do it in the style of std::optional:
return match(v, [](int i){ … })
       .or_else([](const std::string& s){ … })
       .or_else_if<std::is_fundamental>([](double d){ … })
       …;

To summarize, these changes would avoid magic incantations (v >>= m) and avoid adding things to the global namespace unnecessarily.
How to do it in C++17 and later
I agree with indi that I don't think it's worth writing this functionality when it's 2024, and you should be using at least C++17 already. Once you can use a newer version of C++, you get most of what you need from the standard library. The only issue might be that you want the behavior of trying each pattern in sequence and use the first matching one, which is something you can't do with an overloaded{…}. However, you can try to make a class that acts like an overload set, but instead stores a tuple of functions, and which has an operator() that tries them all in sequence. This way, you'd be able to write something like:
return std::visit(match_sequence{
                      [](int){…},
                      [](const std::string& s){…},
                      …
                      match_type<std::vector, int>([](const auto& v){…})
                  }, v);

What about functions taking multiple parameters?
You'll notice that std::visit() can take more than two parameters; the first is a function, the rest of the parameters are variants. The function is called with the value of each of the variants. This is something that is very hard to support with your current syntax, but if you use the style I recommend above, you can write something like:
using MyVariant = std::variant<int, double, std::string, std::vector<int>>;

static std::string match(const MyVariant& v1, const MyVariant& v2) {
    pattern_matcher(v1, v2)
    .match([](int i, int j){…})
    …;
}
```


>>= has a lower precedence than | (and there're not many of those to choose from), so it will be called on an already constructed set of matchers. pattern_matcher(v) | .. | will make the implementation way more difficult and I there will be a possible runtime overhead: each operator| call will be an invocation, which would either execute or be a no-op. This was my first consideration.

std::visit(match_sequence{...}) is a good suggestion. It does look very verbose, but provides a better understanding for the user who is already familiar with std::visit. I think I can have it as the initial interface and if I want, I could provide the piping version over that

I don't think it's worth writing this functionality when it's 2024 Ubuntu 16.04 still exists in 2024 though. mpark::variant works there just fine. If it wasn't a library that should be usable with older compilers, I wouldn't list it as a point in my question.

I also considered a version with member functions, but in order to invoke the constructed object, I'd need to make the call with variant at the end: match.m_is<>().m_is<>().m_if<>()(variant); This is IMO less clear than hacking around the precedence using operator overloading. operator>>= is very unlikely to be confused with bitshifting in this context. I agree that it is a weak point that adds to mental overhead. But it's a single thing to get familiar with

Overall, I think I'll go with a combination of your 2 points: std::visit and member functions. I am not fond of verbose names, however. std::visit(pm.m([](...){...}).m_is<std::vector, int>([](...){...}).m_is<is_fundamental>([](...){...}), variant); (imagine proper formatting). This will allow to not depend on the actual variant header, so it can be easily used with both std::visit and mpark::visit

regarding multiple parameters: I don't think "with predicates support" part is possible or feasible there. In practice I didn't see a lot of usage of std::visit with multiple variants. std::visit with a single variant itself if practically rather rare because a lot of people consider it hard to use/read
